# In shopify-api-node how to get the order greater than the order id

Tags: node.js, shopify, shopify-app

I am new to node js and shopify app develpoment . I need to get the order above some id.  I am using **shopify-api-node** to get the shopify API details

```
  shopify.order.list({ limit: 3 })
        .then(function(orderData){
           console.log(orderData);
          });
```

The above returns top 3 orders . then how i get the order greater than the id. i try `shopify.order.list({ id > 345666466464864 })` . But it is not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the since_id params, as mentioned here : https://help.shopify.com/en/api/reference/orders/order#index

`shopify.order.list({ since_id: 345666466464864 })
 .then(function(orderData){
    console.log(orderData);
 });`